# Getting culture (locale) independent WMI property

Tags: c#, wmi, locale, cultureinfo

I need to get the power settings for a machine using WMI. I am using the [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904534(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the required values. I need specific values from the list returned. The following C# code does this:

```
string NamespacePath = @"root\cimv2\power";
string powerPlanClass = "Win32_powerplan";
string powerSettingClass = "Win32_PowerSettingDataIndex";

ManagementClass powerPlanManagementClass = new ManagementClass(NamespacePath + ":" + powerPlanClass);
ManagementObject powerPlanManagementObject = null;
foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in powerPlanManagementClass.GetInstances())
{
    if (managementObject["IsActive"] != null && Boolean.Parse(managementObject["IsActive"].ToString()))
    {
        powerPlanManagementObject = managementObject;
    }
}

Dictionary<string, PowerSetting> powerItems = new Dictionary<string, PowerSetting>()
    {
       {"AC", new PowerSetting() },
       {"DC", new PowerSetting() }
    };


foreach (ManagementObject oObject in powerPlanManagementObject.GetRelated(powerSettingClass))
        {
            var instanceId = oObject["instanceId"];
            string[] powerSourceSettings = instanceId.ToString().Split(new string[] { @"\" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var powerSourceType = powerSourceSettings[2];
            ManagementObjectCollection managementObjects = oObject.GetRelated("Win32_PowerSetting");
            var elementName = string.Empty;
            foreach (var managementObject in managementObjects)
            {
                elementName = managementObject["ElementName"].ToString();
            }
            var indexValue = uint.Parse(oObject["settingindexvalue"].ToString());

            if (elementName.Equals("Hibernate after",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {                    
                if (powerSourceType.Equals("AC", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    powerItems["AC"].HibernateAfter = indexValue;
                }                    
            }
        }
```

Note the match to the string "Hibernate after". This works on a machine with locale en-us but does not work with a different locale. Is there any other way to get the WMI property independent of the machine's locale?

Comment: Post complete code. I can guess but not sure exactly what you are talking about.

Comment: Don't compare to a hard coded string - instead have the "Hibernate after" in culture specific resource files, and do a comparison tot he resource string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can use GUID in the `InstanceID` of [Win32_PowerSetting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd904532.aspx) class instead of `ElementName`. In my machine, it is `Microsoft:PowerSetting\{9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364}`. Although I couldn't find official document, this GUID, `9d7815a6-7ee4-497e-8888-515a05f02364` seems to be common for some Windows versions and locales as the identifier for "hibernate after" or "hibernate idle".

Comment: Validated on a couple of machines and it seems to be same across. Will use this GUID for finding the setting.